# SendGrid: Deserialization of Email Activity API JSON Response Not Populating Objects

Tags: c#, json, sendgrid, restsharp, sendgrid-api-v3

I am calling SendGrid's Email Activity API using the RestSharp RestClient and it is properly returning data via a standard JSON response.

However, I'd like to deserialize that into a C# object since it would be much easier to work with than a raw JSON string. So I created a C# class that has public properties for each field in the JSON response, and gave them annotations with the exact name of the JSON fields.

But when I call JsonDeserializer().Deserialize>(response), while there's no error/exception, all of the fields in the objects are NULL.

Any ideas what's wrong? (You can just take out the "EventType" references as it's not really relevant here). Relevant code is below.

I'm using RestSharp v106.6.10.0 and Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0 (the latter probably older but that's the library we normally use).
Project is .NET v4.6.1

```
    private void QuerySendGridForEmailActivity(EventType eventType)
    {
string query = string.Empty;

RestClient client = null;//new RestClient(emailActivityEndpoint);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
request.AddParameter("limit", "1000");

if (eventType == EventType.Opens)
{
    //    request.AddParameter("query", WebUtility.UrlEncode("(Contains(events,\"open\"))"));

    client = new RestClient(emailActivityEndpoint + "?limit=10&query=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("(Contains(events,\"open\"))"));
}

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    this.emailActivityEvents = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<List<EmailActivityEvent>>(response);

    int i = 0;

}
else
{

}
    }

    public class EmailActivityEvent
    {
[DeserializeAs(Name = "from_email")]
public string FromEmail { get;set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "msg_id")]
public string MessageId { get; set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "subject")]
public string Subject { get; set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "to_email")]
public string ToEmail { get; set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "status")]
public string Status { get; set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "opens_count")]
public int OpensCount { get; set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "clicks_count")]
public int ClicksCount { get; set; }

[DeserializeAs(Name = "last_event_time")]
public DateTime LastEventTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I don't use RestSharp, but usually you need to access the Content of the response, not the response itself for the body payload.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but the RestSharp JsonDeserializer does expect an IRestResponse object. I just tried updating Newtonsoft.Json as we were using an old version but that didn't seem to have any effect. Dang it. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: Try deserializing `response.Content` with a typed (<T>) client instead of `response` as in the sample [here](http://restsharp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should've gotten this earlier but I didn't think I needed to do this.

I had to add another class that I named "EmailActivity" that just has a List<> of the email events, with a deserialize annotation matching the actual name of the item in JSON. Like this:

```
public class EmailActivity
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "messages")]
        public List<EmailActivityEvent> Events { get; set; }
    }
```

Then just adjust the deserialize call slightly to this:

```
var emailActivity = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<EmailActivity>(response);
```

And that did it. Duh.

Just FYI, the JSON being returned was in this format:

```
{"messages":
[{
    "from_email":"from@email.com",
    "msg_id":"msgid",
    "subject":"Test",
    "to_email":"to@email.com",
    "status":"delivered",
    "opens_count":0,
    "clicks_count":0,
    "last_event_time":"2019-11-26T20:30:02Z"
},
{
    "from_email":"from@email.com",
    "msg_id":"msgid",
    "subject":"Test",
    "to_email":"to@email.com",
    "status":"delivered",
    "opens_count":0,
    "clicks_count":0,
    "last_event_time":"2019-11-26T20:30:01Z"
},
{
    "from_email":"from@email.com",
    "msg_id":"msgid",
    "subject":"Test",
    "to_email":"to@email.com",
    "status":"delivered",
    "opens_count":0,
    "clicks_count":0,
    "last_event_time":"2019-11-25T22:06:25Z"
}
]}
```

Thanks for your comments!